# Prove $\hat{f'}(n)=2\pi in\hat{f}(n)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

The prompt is: Let $f \in C(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}; \mathbb{C})$ be a differentiable function with $f'$ continuous. Show that $f'$ is also in $C(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}; \mathbb{C})$ and that ̂$\hat{f'}(n)=2\pi in \hat{f}(n)$ for all integers $n$.

I need help on the second part of the question. I've used integration by parts to show
$$\hat{f'}(n)=\int f'(x)e^{-2\pi inx}dx$$
$$e^{-2\pi inx}\int f'(x)dx-\int(-2\pi in)e^{-2\pi inx}\int f'(x)dxdx$$
$$e^{-2\pi inx}f(x)+2\pi in\int f(x)e^{-2\pi inx}dx$$

My answer would be correct if it weren't for that leading $e^{-2\pi inx}f(x)$, but I don't know how to get rid of it or what I did wrong.

Edit:
I found out what I did wrong. My bounds were from 0 to 1, so the leading term when integrated becomes $f(1)-f(0)$. And since it's periodic, $f(1)=f(0)$. So the leading term cancels and leaves the rest of the equation.